# New Ubuntu PC build gets stuck during boot

Tags: boot, nvidia, 22.04

I'm just after installing Ubuntu 22.04 on my new PC. That all went fine and at the end of installation it prompted me to restart the system, so I clicked restart, but as the system was rebooting, it got stuck on the below screen.

[image]

The final line being:

> audit: type=1400 audit(1675386312.327.39): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=987 comm="cups-browsed" capability=23 capname="sys_name"

As this wasn't making any progress, I was forced to hold the power button down and shut off the system hoping that everything would work fine when I started it again, but no, I'm getting the exact same thing.

My graphics card is a Nvidia Rtx 3060, if it's relevant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Boot in a safe mode and install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Nope, I seen that alright

Comment: How do I boot in safe mode?

Comment: If you've seen that, then it explains everything. Safe mode is in grub menu.

Comment: Safe mode isn't in my grub menu I'm afraid :)

Comment: It is in advanced options -> recovery mode.

Comment: An easier option will be to use `nomodeset`.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the help